# Using NServiceBus + StructureMap + MVC5

Tags: nservicebus, structuremap, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting some really weird errors, see the repro here - https://github.com/tonyeung/nservicebus-structuremap-mvc5

1. **A strongly-named assembly is required**.
2. Could not load file or assembly 'NServiceBus, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's **manifest definition does not match the assembly reference**.
3. Unable to find the exported Type's in assembly NServiceBus.Core, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c.  One or more of the assembly's dependencies may be missing. **Could not load file or assembly 'Raven.Abstractions**, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

for error number 1 - I had the configuration all set to go, but then it says strong name is needed.
for error number 2 - I commented out the configuration (whats i the repro right now), and I get the manifest error.
for error number 3 - not in repro since its my live project - I have structuremap inject an object that handles my message sending - wanted to create a repro for this, but since i can't even get a simple project going, I'm asking for help now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you having issues is because your MVC project outputs an assembly named "nservicebus.dll" which clashes the NServiceBus.dll assembly.

Rename the assembly of your MVC5 project to something that doesn't clash and then uncomment the code in the global.cs file.